# How do I verify a smart contract on testnet bscscan?

Tags: testnets, bsc, chainlink

I deployed a smart contract on Binance Smart chain testnet, and I'm trying to verify it. Through hardhat, it needs an API Key, but it doesn't look like you can get an API key for testnet.bscscan.com.

If I copy and paste my solidity code manually and try to Verify and Publish from the testnet BSCScan page, it doesn't work because it is importing @chainlink libraries and I get the error `ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol` not found: File import callback not supported"

Is there a way to get around that error?

Comment: It seems someone asked the question before. Can you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376632/how-to-create-binance-test-api-key

Comment: Check this documentation provided by bsc testnet https://testnet.bscscan.com/apidoc#contracts